# PL/SQL - cannot access rows from a non-nested table item oracle

Tags: oracle

Can this package result be called from a procedure or function
the goal is to put that select into a procedure or function
so that when I call the procedure or function the result of the select is displayed.

This is the package i am using regarding this

```
create or replace PACKAGE get_cash_flow 
IS
type type_rec
IS
  record
  (
    asofdate    VARCHAR2(30),
   cfValue VARCHAR2(30));
type type_aa
IS
  TABLE OF type_rec INDEX BY pls_integer;
  FUNCTION func_aa RETURN type_aa;
END;
```

---

```
create or replace PACKAGE body get_cash_flow
 IS
  FUNCTION func_aa
    RETURN type_aa
  IS
    l_aa_var1 get_cash_flow.type_aa;
    BEGIN
    FOR loop_aa IN
     (
      SELECT  rownum rn,
      asofdate, cash_inflow + TRANSFERS  +ASSET_INFLOW +      INTEREST_INCOME_LONG + DIVIDEND_INCOME - CASH_OUTFLOW
       - ASSET_OUTFLOW-CASH_OUTFLOW -ASSET_OUTFLOW + INTEREST_INCOME_SHORT + MANAGEMENT_FEE + OTHER_FEES+EXPENSES  cfValue 
      FROM eod_value_account_mtbl 
      order by  asofdate

      --where  nf_account_id = '0208EA227E0B463ADA8BC413BA1A4D87'
      --FETCH FIRST 1500000 rows only
       FETCH FIRST 500 rows only
     )
    LOOP
      l_aa_var1(loop_aa.rn).asofdate  :=loop_aa.asofdate;
      l_aa_var1(loop_aa.rn).cfValue:=loop_aa.cfValue;
     END LOOP loop_aa;
    RETURN l_aa_var1;
  END func_aa;
  END get_cash_flow;
```

here is the select I am trying to implement in a procedure or function

```
select *
  from
  get_cash_flow.func_aa();
  
 declare     
 vcResult CLOB := NULL;
    l_aa_var1 get_cash_flow.type_aa;
  BEGIN
  l_aa_var1:=get_cash_flow.func_aa;

   SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
     JSON_OBJECT( KEY 'cfDate' VALUE asofdate,KEY 'cfValue' VALUE cfValue )
     FORMAT JSON
     RETURNING CLOB
   ) AS json
   into vcResult
FROM    (
  SELECT asofdate,cfValue
  FROM
  TABLE(l_aa_var1)

  );
dbms_output.put_line('vcResult: '||  vcResult);

 END;
```

Expected result in one line data type in clob

Comment: "Can this package result" What package? Your code has a `SELECT` statement and an anonymous PL/SQL block but no package. Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with the DDL/DML (`CREATE PACKAGE`, `CREATE PACKAGE BODY`, `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT`) statements for your sample code and sample data; an explanation of the logic you are trying to implement; the issues/errors with your code; and the expected output.

Comment: I added more info on this